# Перестал работать проброс портов в Debian

Tags: linux, debian, nat, ufw

Есть три устройства.
Одно, с которого я хочу подключиться.
Второе, на которое я хочу подключиться.
И третье, между ними, через которое я хочу подключиться и на котором делаю проброс портов.
Проброс порта следующим образом:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5034 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.34:22
```

Некоторые порты работаю и я спокойно могу подключиться по ssh через этот маршрут.
Но через некоторые порты подключиться не выходит вообще, хотя раньше можно было.
Для себя откопал, что в логе /var/log/ufw.log в момент, когда я хочу подключиться через проблемный порт появляются такие строчки:

```
Jul 11 13:04:58 server kernel: [ 1637.309108] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:12:6c:02:0a:0e:8e:5d:4e:a7:f0:00:05:00 SRC=11.22.33.44 DST=55.66.77.88 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=27333 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=5066 DPT=5034 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Но если остановить ufw, то всё равно через пробленые порты не подключиться, а в логе ничего не пишется.
Есть также порты, через которые также не удаётся подключение, но в логе ufw ничего не пишет, даже если он включен.
Порты эти не должны быть кемто заняты, netstat ничего не показал, да и я пробовал 40000+

В чём может быть дело? Как можно проверить, что идёт не так?

Answer (score 0):

Если не фаерволл, то apparmor или selinux.

Для начала просмотреть все правила фаервола:

```
sudo iptables-save
```

Если там нет блокировок, то смотрите лог тут

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

или

```
journalctl -f -l SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
```